# Dictionary of KeyValuePair as DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, dictionary, datagridview

If got the following Object:

```
Dictionary<int,KeyValuePair<int,string>> myData;
```

Now I want to assign this Data to a DataGrid.

Setting the DataPropertyName of the Columns to "Key" or "Value" works just fine (containing the Key (int) and the Value (keyvaluepair) of the Dictionary.

But I want to Display the Key and Value of the Pair inside a column.

`colWhatever.DataPropertyName="Value.Value"` does not seem to work.

Is there even a way to do this or do I have to create a class with three Properties for that?

Comment: It's not obvious to me what you want here. There could be any number of entries in the inner dictionary - are you expecting these all to display in one cell somehow?

Comment: @Chris Ballard "colWhatever" is a Column, not a Cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to implement it. You could work with a ViewModel and bind a `List<T>` of this viewmodel, for sample:

Create the ViewModel

```
public class DataViewModel
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public int ValueKey { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }    
}
```

Create a method to convert the `Dictionary<int,KeyValuePair<int,string>>` to the `List<DataViewModel>`:

```
public static List<DataViewModel> Convert(Dictionary<int,KeyValuePair<int,string>> dic)
{
    return dic.Select(item => new DataViewModel() { Key = item.Key, ValueKey = item.Value.Key, Value = item.Value.Value }).ToList();
}
```

and apply this list in the `DataSource` property:

```
grid.DataSource = Convert(myData);
```

On the `DataPropertyName` apply a property from the List type.

```
grid.DataPropertyName = "Value";
```

Comment: That's what I meant with "or do I have to create a class with three properties for that"

Comment: No way to implement it, creating a List<T> is the simple way.

Comment: +1 for "There is no way to implement it". Even if it is not what I wanted to hear :)

Comment: I aggree, could be nice to have a grid with support to navigate by properties like your posted: `Value.Property`. Maybe extend grid with reflection could work haha